# Geofence Serivce triggered not fire

Tags: java, android, google-maps, kotlin, android-geofence

I am using google Geofence service in my current project for track the user movements but I did not get the any proper geofence triggers as exit and enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geofencing combines awareness of the user's current location with awareness of the user's proximity to locations that may be of interest. To mark a location of interest, you specify its latitude and longitude. To adjust the proximity for the location, you add a radius. The latitude, longitude, and radius define a geofence, creating a circular area, or fence, around the location of interest.

for more Info please refer

https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing